# Android: How to add padding to navigation drawer icon in the action bar

Tags: android

I am still struggling with finding a way to add padding/margin space between the navigation drawer icon in the action bar and the screen (top left of screen). Thanks in advance and I am trying to find any solution so either java or xml is perfect.

Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

For padding, you can use:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: Hi sorry that doesnt work, I want to add padding to the action bar/navigation drawer icon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tweak,

What you can do is that you can put the Navigation drawer icon to transparent and instead of application icon set the drawer icon.In that way the drawer icon will be moved away from left side of your screen.

```
ActionBar bar;
bar = getActionBar();
bar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drawer));//where R.drawable.ic_drawer is your drawer icon

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer_transparent, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    )
```

I hope this helps you in some way.